# Unnecessary scroll bar in "User Reputation Leagues"

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

[Here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2017-01-01) every fourth line has a scroll bar:

[image]

Browser: Google Chrome 63.0.3239.108 64 bit or Yandex.Browser 17.11.1.988

OS: Windows 10 10.0.16299.125 64 bit

The browser has a scale of 100%

The OS has a screen size of 125%:

[image]

In Firefox, Edge, IE problem is missing

In Windows 7 with a scale of 125%, the problem is also missing

Comment: @rene, the browser has a scale of 100%

Comment: Ok, I set the scale in the browser to 80%. 1,25 * 0,8 = 1. The problem remains.

Comment: It's just some rep on its way bubbling up to Jon Skeet's first mega.